# Ensuring storage of Redux state and preventing visibility in browser Developer Tools

Tags: redux, react-redux, local-storage, metamask, redux-persist

I need guidance on securely storing the persisted Redux state locally, ensuring it cannot be accessed or displayed through browser development tools. I want to understand the strategies and techniques used by metamask-extension to achieve this level of security. Any insights, code snippets, or recommended best practices would be highly appreciated.

I have attempted to utilize `redux-persist-transform-encrypt` to encrypt and store the Redux state locally.

```
const encryptKey = encryptTransform({
  secretKey: "secrete-key",
});

const encryptionTransform = createTransform(
  (inboundState, key) => {
    return encryptKey.in(inboundState, key);
  },
  (outboundState, key) => {
    return encryptKey.out(outboundState, key);
  }
);

const customStore = localforage.createInstance({
  name: "Extension",
  storeName: "Extension Storage",
});

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage: customStore,
  transform: [encryptionTransform],
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  appState: appStateReducer,
  wallet: walletReducer,
  userPreferences: preferenceReducer,
  connectedWebsites: connectedWebsiteReducer,
  announcements: announcementsReducer,
  language: languageReducer,
});

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  devTools: false,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: false,
    }),
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

However, I encountered an issue where the encrypted data is still visible in the browser's developer tools as `persist:root`.

[image]

In contrast, metamask-extension manages to hide the persisted data and securely store the encrypted vault/state in the following location locally:

---

`C:\\Users\\USER_NAME\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Local Extension Settings\\nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn.`

---

I am seeking guidance on how to achieve similar secure storage of the encrypted persisted Redux state as implemented by metamask-extension.

Comment: This post doesn't appear to be significantly different, improved, or more focused than your previous [post](/q/76318602/8690857). Have you explored alternative `redux-persist` [storage solutions](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#storage-engines)?

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you for your response. I have investigated several alternative options for redux-persist, but they all appear to display sensitive information in the developer tools. This poses a security risk for storing confidential data like seed phrases or private keys. I noticed that Metamask creates a file to store persisted information, and I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions you can provide on this matter.

Comment: How can this possibly be secure if the user has access to the JS runtime that stores data? I can just put a breakpoint in the right line and inspect variables in the devtools. There's probably a reason that software like 1Password also uses a browser extension, not client side code to persist data.

Answer (score 2):

Metamask is a browser extension and probably uses one of the `storage` solutions for browser extensions, which would explain that file you found. I would assume they use [`storage.local`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/local), which is not to be confused with `localStorage`, which is to be used by websites, not extensions.